# Is "FOIL", used as a verb, understandable outside New York State?

Tags: american-english, acronyms

> FOIA = Freedom of Information Act (federal U.S. law)
>
> FOIL = Freedom of Information Law (New York State)

From this, I have frequently heard and read FOIL used as a verb, by journalists and ordinary well-educated people, for example:

> I FOILed them for such-and-so information.

What do people say in other states?

Comment: If I see "FOIL," I'm expecting to [multiply binomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method).

Comment: @ruakh - I put in a clarification.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: I live in Michigan and have not heard this usage before. Like @SomethingDark said in the comments, "If I see 'FOIL,' I'm expecting to multiply binomials." I am about to study as a journalist at Michigan State University and have yet to hear this. Sorry if I wasn't much help!

Comment: I'd classify that as jargon- used only by people *in-the-know*.  I suppose those people could reside anywhere, but I'm definitely not one of them.

Comment: When the villainous bad guys get thwarted because their secrets are revealed do they say: "Curses! FOILed again!"

Comment: To many old IBMers, "foil" means "overhead transparency" (which means [viewgraph](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/viewgraph)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember how I learned this, maybe I posted on Law SE, but anyway, it turns out the answer is

> I *FOIAed* [or foiaed] them.

It works better in spoken language than written.  If one needs something formal there's

> I filed a FOIA request.

Answer (score 1):

suggest use just F.O.I. (FOI-ed as verb) last letter unnecessary here Ontario, Canada. No matter where you go Freedom of Information legislation means "restriction of public access to govt activities"

Comment: Help me understand why you say *restriction*.  I thought it was the other way around?  That FOI laws help members of the public GET access to govt docs and activities?